# How to maximize the differences between multiple versions of a quiz

Tags: combinatorics

To help detect cheating, I can create multiple versions of a quiz, with 1 or 2 changed questions on each version.

If I create alternate versions of 3 of the questions, I can create 4 versions of the quiz and ensure that any two different versions have exactly 2 questions different between them, by arranging the question like this:

```
         | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| Quiz 1 |   ver 1    |   ver 1    |   ver 1    |
| Quiz 2 |   ver 2    |   ver 2    |   ver 1    |
| Quiz 3 |   ver 2    |   ver 1    |   ver 2    |
| Quiz 4 |   ver 1    |   ver 2    |   ver 2    |
```

Any 2 quizzes from the table above have exactly two questions different between them.

This could also be expressed as 4 binary numbers that have 2 bits different between any pair: 000, 110, 011, and 101.

What is the mathematical principle here, and how could this be expanded to a larger number of questions and quizzes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between two versions is the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the binary numbers representing the two.  It just counts the number of bit positions that disagree.  The [Hamming codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) give you the number of questions that you need to have two versions of to get a distance of three.  The Hamming $(7,4)$ code says you can get $2^4$ different tests at a minimum distance of $3$ with $7$ questions that have two versions.

Comment: Thanks, I had found the "Hamming distance" stuff, but hadn't made the connection to Hamming codes. Just to clarify - my original example is not using Hamming codes at all, but just a single parity bit.. which gives me a minimum Hamming distance of 2. The fact that it's exactly 2 in all cases is a coincidence, and a side-effect of using only 3 bits, right?

Comment: You can use a single parity bit with any number of data bits.  As you say, that gives you a distance $2$ and can detect single bit errors but not correct any.  There is a theorem that you can get as large a distance as you like with a constant fraction of check bits by increasing the block size.